# If statement for multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.4

Here is my aim in an example. If you could help me complete it that would be great!

```
exampleNumbers = [One,Uno,Two,Dos]
randomNumber = random.choice(exampleNumbers)
```

From here on I want it to then change `randomNumber` to 1 if the random selection of `exampleNumbers`is **One** or **Uno** or change `randomNumber` to 2 if the random selection of `exampleNumbers` is **Two** or **Dos**.

I think I can do it using an if statement, however I am unsure on how to use an if statement with multiple values.

So basically if the random selection is **Two** for example, I want it to then make `randomNumber` = 2.

Sorry if I haven't explained this very well, I'm slowly getting there but my knowledge and terminology is still at an amateur state. I'll happily tick and vote up any great answers!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Why don't you just pick from the items you actually want?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe One possible reason could be that the OP wants to weight the likelihood of certain values by providing more of a chance for those to be selected. Of course this is just speculation on my part.

Comment: @Andy you can weight by just putting appropriate proportions, in this case `random.choice((1, 1, 2, 2))` (excluding the obvious simplification!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the operator `in`:

```
if randomNumber in (One,Uno):
    randomNumber = 1
else:
    randomNumber = 2
```

Or the classic `or` boolean operator:

```
if randomNumber == One or randomNumber == Uno:
    randomNumber = 1
else:
    randomNumber = 2
```

The `in` is great to check for a lot of values.

The `or`, with the other boolean operators `and` and `not` can be used to build arbitrarily complex logical expressions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `and` and `or` to compound statements. and for multiple statements you can also use parenthesis (ie: `(True and False) or (False or True)`). There does exist an order of operations which is basically left to right. So for you question you can do

```
if(num == "two" or num == "dos"):
    //do things
elif (num == "one" or num == "uno"):
    //do other things
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also define options:

```
options = { One : thisIsOne,
              Uno : thisIsOne,
              Two : thisIsTwo,
              Dos : thisIsTwo,
}

def thisIsOne()
  randomNumber = 1

def thisIsTwo()
  randomNumber = 2
```

You can then simply call `options[randomNumber]()`

I'm a little rusty with my python but I'm pretty sure that works (but so does the previous answer by rodrigo! matter of preference and reusability)